# How to parse object with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: jquery, arrays, parsing, object

How to parse an object like this with jQuery or javascript:

```
Object { 4: Array[1], 5: Array[1] } //arrSrok

$.each(arrSrok, function(srokID, arrKhum) {
  console.log(arrKhum); //runs only once, and I got srokID = 4, arrKhum empty
});
```

It seems that arrKhum cannot be assigned with an array. What do I miss?

Though I can parse an object with the following format successfully

```
Object { 1: Object, 2: Object }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I tried and it seems to be working correctly

```
var someObject = { 4: [3,4], 5: [1,2] };
```

**EDIT:** If you want to loop through array, you can use `$.isArray` provided by JQuery

```
$.each(someObject, function(key, value) {
  if($.isArray(value)){
     $.each(value,function(key1,value1){
      console.log(value1);
     });
  }
});
```

Here is the Link

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1odathfd/2/)**

Comment: I did not test it with $.isArray, but it should not be a problem if we already know that it is an array. It seems that I followed the same syntax. I will also check if the problem is somewhere else. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah..it shudnt be a problem if you know its already an array

Comment: My problem just disappeared miraculously, and the parsing works perfectly now using similar way to your suggested one (without $.isArray() testing). I did not find the cause of the problem because I just restarted localhost server and it worked. Anyway, thanks a lot, and I accept your answer.